# HTML Radio buttons runat=server not working

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="rdbActive">Active</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio inline" for="rdbActive0">
        <input name="rdbActive" id="rdbActive0" value="Yes" checked="checked" type="radio">Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio inline" for="rdbActive1">
        <input name="rdbActive" id="rdbActive1" value="No" type="radio">No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I make this runat=server?

For text input all I do is:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="txtDescription">Description</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="txtDescription" runat="server" name="txtDescription" placeholder="" class="input-large" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

..and I'm able to access it from code behind. If I add it to any radio button I get a 500 server error.

Answer (score 3):

You may create radio button with `runat="server"` as:

```
<asp:RadioButton id="RadioButton1" AutoPostBack="True|False" Checked="True|False" GroupName="GroupName" Text="label" TextAlign="Right|Left" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckedChangedMethod" runat="server" />
```

Where `OnCheckedChangedMethod` is the code-behind method which is invoked when the radio button is checked.

See this [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xke2zw4x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN website.